# concat all rows in one rows

Tags: sql

Hi i need to concat all rows from my table.
I have this query `select * from table1;` this table contains 400 fields 
i cannot do this `select column1 ||','||column2||','||.....from table1`
can someone help e to fix it using select * from table1 to concatinate all rows.
And thank you.

Comment: please tag your dbms as well.

Comment: this looks like oracle is it?  and it doesn't seem your concating the rows... it seems like you want to combine the columns to return 1 column many rows?  if that's not the case, post sample data and expected results.

Comment: if you are using db2 or oracle look at LISTAGG() function.

Comment: mysql has  GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: sql server -- FOR XML PATH

Comment: long story short... platform dependent, what platform are you using?

Comment: Postgres has `string_agg()`

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle (and similar in other DBMS) you could use system tables.... and do this in two steps:

Assuming you want to combine all the columns into 1 column for X rows...

**STEP 1:**

```
SELECT LISTAGG(column_Name, '|| Chr(44)||')   --this char(44) adds a comma
           within group (order by column_ID)  as Fields
            --Order by column_Id ensures they are in the same order as defined in db.
FROM all_tab_Cols 
WHERE table_name = 'YOURTABLE' 
  and owner = 'YOUROWNER'
--Perhaps exclude system columns  
  and Virtual_Column = 'NO'
```

**STEP 2:**

Copy the results into a new SQL statement and execute.
The  would look something like `Field1|| Chr(44)||Field2|| Chr(44)||Field3`

```
SELECT <results> 
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

which would result in a comma separated list of values in 1 column for all rows of `YOURTABLE`

If the length of all the columns (along with , space and ||) would exceed the 4000 characters allowed... we can use a clob data type instead through the use of XML objects...

*** Replace step 1 with ***

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(Column_ID,Column_Name,'|| Chr(44)||').extract('//text()') order by Column_ID).GetClobVal(),'|| Chr(44)||') fields
FROM all_tab_Cols 
WHERE table_name = 'YOURTABLENAME' 
  and owner = 'YOUROWNER'
--Perhaps exclude system columns  
  and Virtual_Column = 'NO';
```

Syntax for the above attributed to [This Oracle thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2548234)  but updated for your needs.

Comment: the problem i have a 400 columns   there something like this SELECT LISTAGG(*, '|| ,||')?

Comment: Did you try it?  The step 1 selects ALL non-virtual columns from the table.schema specified.  step 2 then selects all 400 columns and combines them.  All you would have to do is change YOURTABLE and YOUROWNER to schema and table run it, take the results and paste into 2nd query in step 2 replacing <results> with what you copied.  No manually typing all 400 columns.

Comment: or are you getting a string concat too long error? `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.`